# Frequent crashes after updates in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: crash

System becomes irresponsive when video with audio and chrome application is used simultaneously. Data streaming (youtube) is also freezed.

Is this my configuration issue or updates are normally of that random quality ??
Please suggest. I am no expert in using ubuntu. :)

Comment: Crashes normally indicate a hardware problem. I'm running Ubuntu since years and never had any crashes after updates. As a first step, test if your RAM is still good with [memtest](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MemoryTest), come back to your question and click on [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/580007/edit) below your question and add the findings of running memtest a few hours.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

Answer (score 0):

Tue Feb 10, 2015. In 12.04.x LTS I too am getting constant crashes after getting Ubuntu updates which update Binary Libraries, through either sudo apt-get update or Update Manager. And am having to do at least an hour or more of constant restarts of the system trying to get various functions to load correctly. repeated errors upon reboot such as: "Something went wrong checking for updates." "Error Reporting system has closed unexpectedly." Libra Office Write Failing to start. Firefox Browser Crashing when attempting to open.